# How to detect the currently selected resizable & draggable div and also its coordinates

Tags: jquery, html

In one of my webpage, I have a large container div.I also have a button which when
clicked, generates a new resizable & draggable div and appended to the container div.

So at a time, the container div may contain more than one resizable & draggable div.

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

My code to generate and append resizable & draggable div is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.genUID = function(){ 
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
        var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2000) + 1000);
        var z = Date.now();
        return "uid-" + (x * y * z).toString();        
    }
    $('#btnCreateSelector').click(function() {
        var guid = $.fn.genUID();

        var string = '<div id="' + guid + '" class="sel_area" style="box-sizing: content-box;top: 0; left: 0; width: 140px; height: 140px;">';
        string += "</div>";
        $("#container").append(string);   
        $(".sel_area").resizable({
            handles: "n, e, s, w, nw, ne, sw, se",
        }).draggable();
    });

});
```

Now i want to save the width, height and coordinates of any resizable & draggable div in the database and here lies the problem.
I am unable to figure out as how to detect the currently selected div and also how to determine its current coordinates.

Hope you understand my problem.Any help with code snippet would be highly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: For random id you can use something like `'uid-' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);`, found it [here](https://gist.github.com/gordonbrander/2230317).

Comment: *"Hope you understand my problem"* ....No, not really. Use event callback options of `draggable` plugin to access current element and it's position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you gotta use;

```
    $(document).click(function(e){
      var x = $(e.target).attr('id');
});
```

To get the clicked element and

```
 function handleDragStop( event, ui ) {
  var offsetXPos = parseInt( ui.position.left );
  var offsetYPos = parseInt( ui.position.top );
}
```

To get the position.